# Is there any difference between (?>EXPR|) and (?:EXPR)?+

Tags: regex

In the following I will consider the regular expressions `(?>EXPR|)` and `(?:EXPR)?+`.

Let's say we want to match the string `ABC`.

- Using `(?>A|AB|)C` it will first try to match `A`, then it will fail (because the `A` character is not followed by `C`) and it will try to match `AB` without possibility of backtracking, so it will fail again (because the `A` character has already been consumed) and finally it will match the empty string, failing a third time. Two characters later, it will find the substring `C`, that clearly matches the pattern.
- Using `(?:A|AB)?+C` it will first try to match `A`, then it will fail (because the `A` character is not followed by `C`) and it hasn't got the possibility to go further because of the possessive quantifier `+`. Two characters later, it will find the substring `C`, that clearly matches the pattern.

The question is: even if `(?>EXPR|)` and `(?:EXPR)?+` work in different ways, are they semantically equivalent?

Comment: Possessive quantifiers are equivalent in functioning to atomic groups, both are meant to prevent backtracking into the quantified patterns. If you wrap a set of patterns with a non-capturing group and set a possessive quantifier to this group it behaves as an atomic group. `(?>A|AB)?C` = `(?>A|AB|)C` = `(?:A|AB)?+C`

Answer (score 1):

See the [atomic group referefence](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html):

> An atomic group is a group that, when the regex engine exits from it, automatically throws away all backtracking positions remembered by any tokens inside the group. Atomic groups are non-capturing. The syntax is `(?>group)`. [Lookaround groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are also atomic. Atomic grouping is supported by most modern regular expression flavors, including the [JGsoft](https://www.regular-expressions.info/jgsoft.html) flavor, [Java](https://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html), [PCRE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html), [.NET](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html), [Perl](https://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html), [Boost](https://www.regular-expressions.info/boost.html), and [Ruby](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html). Most of these also support [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), which are essentially a notational convenience for atomic grouping.

Note that possessive quantifiers are a notational convenience for atomic grouping, they are functioning in the same way: they make their patterns match once without allowing any backtracking into these patterns.

If you wrap a set of patterns with a non-capturing group and set a possessive quantifier to this group it behaves as an atomic group.

Since `(?>A|AB)?` is an optional atomic group  that matches `A` or `AB` (and atomic groups are non-capturing), it is the same as `(?>A|AB|)` that matches either `A`, `AB` or an empty string (so, it is also optional in a way).

```
(?>A|AB)?C = (?>A|AB|)C = (?:A|AB)?+C
```